# How to parse XML without specific tag names in C#

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing

I've the following XML, which I'd like to parse in my C# code. However, I don't have any idea how this should be done.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<results>
  <fields>
    <field>COLUMN_NAME_1</field>
    <field>COLUMN_NAME_2</field>
    <field>COLUMN_NAME_3</field>
    <field>COLUMN_NAME_4</field>
  </fields>
  <rows>
    <row>
      <col>value_for_column_1</col>
      <col>value_for_column_2</col>
      <col>value_for_column_3</col>
      <col>value_for_column_4</col>
    </row>
    <row>
      <col>value_for_column_1</col>
      <col>value_for_column_2</col>
      <col>value_for_column_3</col>
      <col>value_for_column_4</col>
    </row>
    ...
  </rows>
</results>
```

This is just an example, because I can't provide real data. The structure of XML looks exactly the same. "COLUMN_NAME_" and "value_for_column_" are represented by a string. I'd be very thankful if you could help me.

Comment: Create schema (xsd) template to validate this and use XmlValidatingReader class of .net to validate it.

Comment: @Romil not sure that really achieves much here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, create a [xml document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.aspx) obect. Then get the root node, then access your custom nodes.

```
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.Load(fileName);
    XmlNode root = doc.DocumentElement;
    XmlNode s = root.SelectSingleNode('/' + rootName + '/' + section);
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [`XmlDocument`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.aspx), you can iterate over the [`ChildNodes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.childnodes) property recursively.

e.g.

```
void Recurse(XmlNodeList list)
{ 
     foreach(XmlNode node in list)
     {
         // Do some work
         Recurse(node.ChildNodes);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have noted, [XmlDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.aspx) is one of the most comfortable ways of reading such files. You can iterate through nodes with `foreach`, you can run XPath queries against it, etc.

I'd just like to add, that in the case the XML file is very large (and thus would be impractical to read it all in memory at once), there is an [XmlReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader.aspx) class, that allows you to read the XML file sequentially from the start to the end, keeping only a small part of it in memory.

Answer (score 0):

By using the following, we can get the fields element and the rows element:

- `node.FirstNode` - to get the first child node of the parent
- `node.NextNode` - gets the next sibling node

Load the xml and initialize the columns list.

```
XElement root = XElement.Load(file); // or .Parse(string);
List<List<string>> columns = new List<List<string>>();
```

Get the column headers:

```
XElement fields = (XElement)root.FirstNode;
fields.Elements().Select((x, i) => 
{
    columns.Add(new List<string>());
    columns[i].Add((string)x); 
    return true; // because a select has to return something
}).ToArray();
```

Then get the rows:

```
XElement rows = (XElement)fields.NextNode;
rows.Elements().ToList().ForEach(row =>
    row.Elements().Select((x, i) => 
    { 
        columns[i].Add((string)x); 
        return true; 
    }).ToArray());
```

The columns list will then contain the header followed by all the rows sorted by column.

PS I needed the `.ToArray()'s` for my testing, you may not need them in your project.

Answer (score -1):

Here is the simpliest way to do this:

```
 private static void Main()
 {
        const string xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"yes\"?> <results> ... </results>";
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();

        doc.LoadXml(xml);
        var fieldsCollection  = doc.GetElementsByTagName("fields");
        var rowsCollection = doc.GetElementsByTagName("rows");
 }
```

Comment: OP said he doesn't know tag names

Comment: "The structure of XML looks exactly the same." - this is form topic

Comment: The title, "How to parse XML without specific tag names in C#"